# Drools Fusion: Strange behavior if I cange the filed and use it in the same instant

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

This is my code into an .rdl

```
rule "Fulfilment 24345"
when

$evPtr: LeftArmStretched($tsmp:time)

    eval((3>$tsmp)==true)
then
System.err.println("$tsmp=      "+$tsmp);

end


rule "set timestamp"

when
   $las:LeftArmStretched();
then
   System.out.println("//change timestamp!!");
   $las.setTime(6);
end
```

If I run my example, 1st and 2nd rules fire and print:

```
//change timestamp!!
$tsmp=         6
```

but if `$tsmp=3` the `rule1` does not fire!!!!  (3>6 false!)

If I manually write `eval((3>6)==true)` into rule1, the rule1 doesn't correctly fire!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A change to a fact object must be announced to the Rule Engine, i.e., use

```
modify( $las ){
    setTime( 6 )
}
```

Also, do not rely on rule "set timestamp" being fired first. Use some additional constraint, or salience.

Comment: ok but if I use modify into rule "set timestamp" I create a loop and again rule "set timestamp" fire!